# loginscreen in android pressing backbutton showing values in the fields

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a login screen and registered screen ...when application launches and i click on registerbutton it navigates to register activity...here after entering the fields and press register
button then again comes to loginscreen with the fields enteres is displayed in the `EditFields` (user and password).....

(issue :: 1) here if i prees back button and again open the application then the fields are showing with the values enterd....but here in this situation it have to be empty ....

**Am facing issues :: 1 ..**

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


 User myApplication;

EditText username,passwordField;
 Button login,registerButton;
 CheckBox check;

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String userStored;
    String passwordStored;
     boolean checked =false;
     boolean checkboxvalue;
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_File";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    myApplication = (User) getApplicationContext();


    username =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    passwordField =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    username.setText(myApplication.getUser());
    passwordField.setText(myApplication.getPassword()); 


    registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });





             Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstScreen.class);
             startActivity(intent);


        }
    });






}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    moveTaskToBack(true);

}



 }


public class Register extends Activity {
 User myApplication;


 EditText user,password;
 Button register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    myApplication = (User) getApplicationContext();


    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


    register =(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            myApplication.setUser(user.getText().toString());
            myApplication.setPassword(password.getText().toString());


            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });






}

  }


public class User extends Application {

String user =null;
String password =null;
public String getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


 }
```

Comment: Remove `username.setText(myApplication.getUser());passwordField.setText(myApplication.getPassword()); `  lines from onCreate

Comment: Try finish(); when login / Register process is completed successfully

Comment: You should be clear with the flow.once the user logs in, the login activity should never come again

Comment: You have to use finish() after intent fire or you have to use flags with intent

Comment: i used finish().. in RegisterActivity...but here after register it come to login and here if i press backbutton and open agains showing empty in fields ...but if i press back again and open again then once again it will showing data...

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K ...thanks for reply but if i remove form onceate and place in onStart() am getting same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code i hve gven explanation and help links in comments for the mistakes which u made.

```
    public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    User myApplication;

    EditText username, passwordField;
    Button login, registerButton;
    CheckBox check;

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String userStored;
    String passwordStored;
    boolean checked = false;
    boolean checkboxvalue;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_File";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        myApplication = (User) getApplicationContext();

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        /*
         * Text From the registration screen is showing becauseyou r storing it
         * in application class and setting that values in login screen. So
         * remove below two lines
         */

        // username.setText(myApplication.getUser());
        // passwordField.setText(myApplication.getPassword());

        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
// what is the use of starting activity in oncreate ? remove if its not required
        //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstScreen.class);
        //startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Registration

```
public class Register extends Activity {
    User myApplication;

    EditText user, password;
    Button register;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        myApplication = (User) getApplicationContext();

        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                myApplication.setUser(user.getText().toString());
                myApplication.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

                /*
                 * No need to start the activity again which is already in
                 * stack. For activity life cycle , backstack and instances
                 * check
                 * http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity
                 * .html &
                 * http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-
                 * lifecycle/index.html
                 */

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // FINISH the current activity if its not more required in stack
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Appication

```
public class User extends Application {

    String user = null;
    String password = null;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: username.setText(myApplication.getUser()); passwordField.setText(myApplication.getPassword()); i have give this because with the register values i want to show in login screen...